# ANOVA of pairwise (non-independent) data in R

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, independence, paired-data

I am trying to do a one-way ANOVA of data that is generated from pairwise comparisons, and am having difficulty resolving the problem of non-independence.  I have 12 populations, and for each pairwise combination of the 12 populations, I calculate a value (probably not important to know what the value is, but it is Pianka's index).  Then, each of these comparisons is classified into one of three groups depending on the identity of the two populations in the comparison.  So, my data looks something like this:

**Group 1**      /    **Group 2**   /   **Comparison Type** / **Pianka**

```
 A            B                Lake-Lake          0.4
 A            C                Lake-River         0.3 
 B            C                Lake-River         0.5
 B            D                Lake-River         0.1
 A            D                Lake-River         0.1
 C            D                River-River        0.7
```

So, my independent variable is Comparison Type, and the dependent variable is Pianka.  The problem is, each comparison isn't independent because the groups are in repeated comparisons.  I thought using a repeated measures ANOVA might work, but I don't think it's quite right.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

The Pianka index is a measure of the amount of overlap in time-series data between the two sites (A-D, which are either lakes or rivers). At each site, I measured a variable over six time points, and the Pianka index tells me how similar the two sites are in this variable over time. Pianka is continuous and bounded by (0,1) (1 for total overlap, 0 for no overlap). The research question is not trying to determine if Pianka is null, but rather if it is different depending on the comparison you are making (i.e. lake-lake, lake-stream, or stream-stream).  My hypothesis is that the Lake-River Pianka values are smaller than those for Lake-Lake or River-River (there is less overlap in the variable measured through time).

Comment: How is the Pianka index calculated? E.g., is it a ratio of a continuous variable measured at each location? Is the research question about all the Pianka indices being null, or about each individual index?

Comment: Modified the original post to address the questions asked by half-pass, I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: What are the `A`, ..., `D` groups? Are they related to, say, `Lake`s vs `River`s? You say that Pianka is an overlap, is it continuous & is it bounded w/i (0, 1)?

Comment: Updated original post to answer gung's questions.  A...D are sites which are either lakes or rivers.  So A (a lake) compared with B (also a lake) is a lake-lake comparison.  Pianka is continuous between zero and 1.